# status bar background color differs from view controller

Tags: ios, swift

Sorry guys, this is maybe a duplicate question, but I didn't find any answer to fix my problem. see this [image: picture]

I used this code to change background color of my status bar:

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)

    (UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView).backgroundColor = TGColors.green
    (UIApplication.shared.value(forKey: "statusBar") as! UIView).alpha = 1
}
```

My problem is the color of my ViewControllers's view and status bar are different, regardless of having same color I've set to them. What's wrong with this issue?

also see these pictures for more info:
[image: storyboard structure]

[image: color of my scrollview's contentview]

and this is the constant colors I defined and use inside my application:

```
struct TGColors {
static let green = UIColor(rgb: 0x55CB92).withAlphaComponent(1)    // r: 85, g: 203, b: 146
static let greenBorder = UIColor(rgb: 0xBEEED6).withAlphaComponent(1)    // r: 190, g: 238, b: 214
static let orange = UIColor(rgb: 0xFF7B4E).withAlphaComponent(1)    // r: 255, g: 123, b: 78
static let grey_808080 = UIColor(rgb: 0x505050).withAlphaComponent(1)    // r:80, g: 80, b: 80
static let purpleyPink = UIColor(rgb: 0xB051B7).withAlphaComponent(1)    // r: 176, g: 81, b:183
```

}

Comment: Why do you change the status bar's color (with this unsafe solution) at all? Usually it has the same color as the view (controller) behind it.

Comment: it was not the same color as ViewController, maybe cus I have this ViewController under NavigationController, it was white and cus of this I changed it this way as suggested in several stack overflow posts.

Comment: Delete all your view's constraints and set them again to superView , no need to change background color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only have to set your view controller's view's `backgroundColor` I guess:

```
class YourViewControllerSubclass: UIViewController {
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        view.backgroundColor = TGColors.green
    }
}
```

You can also do this in storyboard instead.

Comment: I don't have navigationBar here, only a statusBar and a ViewController pushed in this way: self.navigationController?.pushViewController(loginVC, animated: true)

Comment: So you use a navigation controller but the navigation bar is hidden? Then where does the back button on the screenshot come from?

Comment: that's a custom thing, it's just an UIImage with a label beside it.

Comment: Ok. Weird. Can you show some more code / UI setup in storyboard?

Comment: After seeing your storyboard setup I guess you only have to set your view controller's view's `backgroundColor` (and remove that status bar stuff).

Comment: tnx for your suggestion: I solved it with this:                                                override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        self.view.backgroundColor = TGColors.green
        self.scrollContentView.backgroundColor = TGColors.green
    }

Comment: You should do it in `viewDidLoad` instead since `viewWillAppear` could be called multiple times. Other than that... you're welcome.